# X-CSRF-Token error with ElasticSearch and AJAX requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, elasticsearch

I have 403 error when I'm trying to send search request in ElasticSearch with AJAX request, using Rails backend.

Answer (score 3):

I added this line in elasticsearch config and now it's working fine for me:

```
http.cors.allow-headers: "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-CSRF-Token"
```